# customize format of #{currentDate} in seam?

Tags: java, date, seam

I just got an answer to my seam question about displaying current date.  Now I'm searching around to find the place to change the format for this feature.  Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<h:outputText value="#{currentDate}">
   <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

See [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details on the format.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the Seam alternative:

```
<h:outputText value="#{currentDate}>
   <s:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="medium" />
</h:outputText>
```